# What happens when Invisible Spell modifies silent image?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, metamagic, illusion

When using the feat Invisible Spell to modify the spell [*silent image*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#silent-image), is it accurate to say that the resulting image will only be seen by those who can see invisibility?

This could add another layer to a deception or even allow the creation of illusions that do not hinder allies, but do these two things actually interact this way?

Comment: Can you specify any reason why do you suspect it wouldn't work the way you describe? Because as it is, I can answer with just "Yes, it actually works this way".

Comment: @annoyingimp I can! I can! *Because the feat Invisible Spell is a poorly-thought-out mess with no rules support!* O, and *Nobody can be absolutely sure how Invisible Spell works until the DM says how it works!* I mean, seriously, the feat Invisible Spell is a headache from the get-go, and *any* question—including this one—about how the feat works is perfectly reasonable, but, possibly, also unanswerable.

Comment: @HeyICanChan The start of your comment gave another way to look at your username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't get much simpler than:

**Yes**

From the description for [Invisible Spell](http://dnd.arkalseif.info/feats/cityscape--53/invisible-spell--1684/index.html):

> Those with detect magic, see invisibility, or true seeing spells or effects active at the time of the casting **will see whatever visual manifestations typically accompany the spell**

And, from the description for Silent Image:

> This spell creates the visual illusion of an object, creature, or force, as visualized by you. The illusion does not create sound, smell, texture, or temperature. You can move the image within the limits of the size of the effect.

**However**, any characters WILL see the material component of your spell *during the casting process* along with any verbal and gesture components required (the material consumed during casting, thank you @KRyan) regardless of Invisible Spell. In this case, a small piece of fleece won't be easily missed but it's something to be kept in mind.

> Note that this feat has no bearing on any components required to cast the enhanced spell, so the spell's source might still be apparent, depending on the situation, despite its effects being unseen.

Comment: At first I thought you were suggesting that the fleece would be visible for the duration of the spell or something, “giving away” the trick or something. Maybe reword to be clearer that the fleece (and the associated chants and gestures) would only be evident when first casting it (so someone who comes by later wouldn’t have those indications that something was amiss).